# Inclusion-exclusion with distribution

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can we distribute $15$ different books to $15$ children (one for each one) then collect the books and again distribute so that no child will get the same book previously received?

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Try to create a simpler problem involving 3 books and 3 children. See how it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are $15!=1307674368000$ ways to distribute the books initially.

By the [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) formula, there are $!15=\text{round}\left(\cfrac{15!}{e}\right)=481066515734$ ways to redistribute the books so that no child gets the same book previously received.

Thus there are $15!\times!15=629078351928420506112000$ ways in total.